# Google Apps script is slow. curious how I can improve upon this

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a bulk email account that has emails forwarded to it from many different emails. I made this script to take a search term from a google sheets cell.  Then it takes the results of that query and sets the value of all the email addresses back into that spreadsheet. I am seeing about 30 second execution time.  I have tried to limit my calls and follow Googles best practice information. But I am quite new at programming so not sure if this is expected.  Any comments on this would be great!

```
function pullPurch() {

  var ss         = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();          // get search term
  var sheet      = ss.getSheetByName('Compare');
  var purchRange = sheet.getRange("B5:B5");
  var purchTerm  = purchRange.getDisplayValue();

  if(purchTerm && purchTerm.length > 2 ){                          // grab threads of messages
    var purchSH  = ss.getSheetByName('Purchases');
    var emails   = [];
    var threads  = GmailApp.search(purchTerm, 0, 500);              
    var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads);

    for (var i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++) {                   //get recipient of emails
      emails.push([messages[i][0].getTo()]);  
      }
    }

    if(emails && emails.length > 0){                                //set values back to sheet
     purchSH.getRange(purchSH.getLastRow()+1, 1, emails.length, 1).setValues(emails);
    }  
  }
```

Comment: Approx how many email addresses are being returned? 30 seconds seems about right for what you are doing. If you look at the execution transcript will see the timing of each call so you'll know better from that.

Comment: Around 150 - 200.